# onActivityResult's resultCode is always 0 while trying to get phone number from contacts

Tags: android, contacts

I saw a lot of similar questions & answers at stackoverflow & google but no luck. onActivityResult's resultCode is always 0 while trying to get phone number from contacts. Here is the code, please help me, I'll very grateful to you.
`

```
package april19ideas.call.blocker;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Collections;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DNDCallBlockerBlackListActivity extends ListActivity {

private static final String TAG = "DNDCallBlockerBlackListActivity";
private static final int PICK_CONTACT = 3;
private static final int PICK_LOG = 4;
private static final String BLACKLIST_PREF = "blacklist";

private ArrayList<String> m_phones;
private ArrayList<String> m_contacts;
private LayoutInflater m_Inflater;
private ArrayAdapter<String> m_adapter;
private SharedPreferences settings;
private int checkedItem;
private Context myContext;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created. Responsible for initializing
 * the UI.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    myContext = this;
    settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(myContext);

    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    if (manager.checkSignatures("april19ideas.call.blocker",
            "april19ideas.call.blocker.key") == PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH) {
        setContentView(R.layout.noad_blacklist);
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.blacklist);
    }

    m_Inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    m_phones = new ArrayList<String>();
    m_contacts = new ArrayList<String>();

    String tmp_phones = settings.getString(BLACKLIST_PREF, "");
    if (tmp_phones != "") {
        String[] tmp_phonesArr = tmp_phones.split(", ");
        Collections.addAll(m_phones, tmp_phonesArr);

        for (String s : m_phones) {
            // search contact for every saved phone number
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                    Uri.encode(s));
            Cursor cur = cr.query(uri,
                    new String[] { PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null,
                    null);
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                String name = cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
                m_contacts.add(name);
            } else {
                m_contacts.add("N/A");
            }
            cur.close();
        }
    } else {
        // do nothing, list is empty
    }

    // this adapter makes the black list visible to user
    m_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.blacklist_list_item, m_phones) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View reusableView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View row;

            if (reusableView == null) {
                row = m_Inflater
                        .inflate(R.layout.blacklist_list_item, null);
            } else {
                row = reusableView;
            }

            TextView tv1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            tv1.setText(getItem(position));

            TextView tv2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
            tv2.setText(m_contacts.get(position));

            return row;
        }
    };
    setListAdapter(m_adapter);

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    // to handle taps on list items
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                final int position, long id) {
            // construct an alert dialog
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(myContext);

            // set icon, title and message
            alert.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
            alert.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            alert.setMessage(m_phones.get(position) + " - "
                    + m_contacts.get(position));

            // configure two buttons
            alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.message_remove,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                            // when OK pressed, go to paypal donations
                            // web page
                            // remove item from list
                            m_phones.remove(position);
                            m_contacts.remove(position);
                            String tmp_phones = "";
                            if (m_phones.size() > 0) {
                                tmp_phones = m_phones.toString();
                                tmp_phones = tmp_phones.substring(1,
                                        tmp_phones.length() - 1);
                            }
                            // save updated list to sharedpreferences
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings
                                    .edit();
                            editor.putString(BLACKLIST_PREF, tmp_phones);
                            editor.commit();
                            // refresh ui
                            m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            // inform user
                            String toast_text = getString(R.string.phone_removed);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    toast_text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

            alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.message_keep,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                            // Canceled. Do nothing.
                        }
                    });

            // show the dialog window
            alert.show();
        }
    });

}


public void pickFromContacts(View target) {
    // start contact list activity to pick one phone number
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
}

public void pickFromCallLog(View target) {
    // start callog list activity to pick one phone number
    Intent intent = new Intent(DNDCallBlockerBlackListActivity.this,
            DNDCallBlockerCallogListActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_LOG);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //resultCode = -1;
    Log.e("resultCode", reqCode+ ":" + resultCode);

    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.e("reqCode",""+reqCode);

    switch (reqCode) {

    case (PICK_CONTACT):
        Log.e("PICK_CONTACT", "PICK_CONTACT" + resultCode);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.e("PICK_CONTACT1", "PICK_CONTACT1");
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            // somehow could be possible that data.getData is null :(
            if (contactData != null) {
                Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                // get selected phone number & contact name
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    try {
                        m_phones.add(c
                                .getString(
                                        c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))
                                .trim());
                        m_contacts
                                .add(c.getString(
                                        c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME))
                                        .trim());
                        // add new item to list
                        String tmp_phones = m_phones.toString();
                        tmp_phones = tmp_phones.substring(1,
                                tmp_phones.length() - 1);
                        // save to sharedpreferences
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString(BLACKLIST_PREF, tmp_phones);
                        editor.commit();
                        // refresh ui
                        m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        // inform user
                        String toast_text = getString(R.string.phone_added);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast_text,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                c.close();
            }
        }
        else {  
            // gracefully handle failure  
            Log.w("DEBUG_TAG", "Warning: activity result not ok");  
        } 
        break;
    case (PICK_LOG):
        Log.e("PICK_LOG", "PICK_LOG");
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.e("PICK_LOG1", "PICK_LOG1");
            String numtoadd = data.getAction();
            m_phones.add(numtoadd);
            // search contact for every saved phone number
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                    Uri.encode(numtoadd));
            Cursor cur = cr.query(uri,
                    new String[] { PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null,
                    null);
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                String name = cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
                m_contacts.add(name);
            } else {
                m_contacts.add("N/A");
            }
            cur.close();
            // add new item to list
            String tmp_phones = m_phones.toString();
            tmp_phones = tmp_phones.substring(1, tmp_phones.length() - 1);
            // save to sharedpreferences
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString(BLACKLIST_PREF, tmp_phones);
            editor.commit();
            // refresh ui
            m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            // inform user
            String toast_text = getString(R.string.phone_added);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast_text,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {  
            // gracefully handle failure  
            Log.w("DEBUG_TAG", "Warning: activity result not ok");  
        }
        break;
    }
}



public void addPhoneNumber(View target) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);

    checkedItem = 0;

    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);

    input.setHint(R.string.hint_typehere);

    alert.setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.manual_phonenumber_types, 0,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    checkedItem = item;
                }
            });

    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    alert.setTitle(R.string.title_add_number);

    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.message_ok,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    String value = input.getText().toString().trim();
                    if (!value.equals("")) {
                        switch (checkedItem) {
                        case 1:
                            value = value.trim() + "*";
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            value = "*" + value.trim() + "*";
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            value = "*" + value.trim();
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                        }
                        // put input to list
                        m_phones.add(value);
                        m_contacts.add("N/A");

                        // add new item to list
                        String tmp_phones = m_phones.toString();
                        tmp_phones = tmp_phones.substring(1,
                                tmp_phones.length() - 1);
                        // save to sharedpreferences
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString(BLACKLIST_PREF, tmp_phones);
                        editor.commit();
                        // refresh ui
                        m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        // inform user
                        String toast_text = getString(R.string.phone_added);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast_text,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.message_cancel,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    alert.show();
}

}
```

`

Comment: Have you permissions: `android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS` and `android.permission.READ_CONTACTS`?

Comment: yes, I added these permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `pickFromContacts` as for getting phone number from contacts :

```
public void pickFromContacts(View target) {
    // start contact list activity to pick one phone number
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
}
```

and if you want to pick contacts by setting setType to `Phone.CONTENT_TYPE` with Intent then change your `pickFromContacts` as:

```
public void pickFromContacts(View target) {
    // start contact list activity to pick one phone number
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
}
```

Comment: @AbuSadatMohammedYasin : what issue you are getting because i have also tested this code in my projects

Comment: When it returns to onActivityResult it can't pass this condition if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK), and thats why I can't pick the selected phone number. resultCode  is 0 & data is null